# Cannot attach EVENT_ROUTE in Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I do not understand why the following code does not work. Perhaps I do not understand something with the EventManger/SharedEventManager ind Zend Framework 2.

For now I could not find anything about this on the internet.

Could it be that the instance of the IndexContoller is already destroyed at EVENT_RENDER and not constructed at EVENT_ROUTE? Perhaps this is the case or am I missing something here?

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

  public function routeEventOccured() {
    echo 'test';
  }

  public function renderEventOccured() {
    echo 'test';
  }

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this,
                                    'routeEventOccured'));
    $this->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, array($this,
                                    'renderEventOccured'));
  } 
}
```

Comment: Controller interaction happens within the `EVENT_DISPATCH`. That's *after* `EVENT_ROUTE`. Therefore it's impossible to a hook into `EVENT_ROUTE` from within your controller. Event-hooks should be declared `onBootstrap()` of your `Module`

Comment: Thanks for this information, like i though. But what is about EVENT_RENDER and EVENT_FINISH? Imho the controller instance is already destroyed at the time they occure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Framework 2 uses the concept of *event*. One class can *trigger* an event,
and other classes may *listen* to events. Technically, triggering an event means just calling another class' "callback" method. The event management is implemented inside of 
the `Zend\Mvc\EventManager` component.

The application's "life" consists of several stages. Each application life stage is initiated by the application by triggering an event. Other classes (either belonging to Zend Framework or specific to your application) may listen 
to events and react accordingly.

Below, the four main events (life stages) are presented:

**Bootstrap**. When this event is triggered by the application, a module has a chance to
register itself as a listener of further application events in its `onBootstrap()` 
callback method.

**Route**. When this event is triggered, the request's URL is analyzed using a *router* class (typically, with 
`Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack` class. If an exact match between the URL and a route
is found, the request is passed to the site-specific controller class assigned to the route.

**Dispatch**. The controller class "dispatches" the request using the corresponding action method 
and produces the data that can be displayed on the web page.

**Render**. On this event, the data produced by the controller's action method are passed for rendering to 
`Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` class. The renderer class uses a 
*view template* file for producing an HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for the information but what is with the events:  EVENT_RENDER and EVENT_FINISH ?